# Floating IDE windows in Qt Designer within Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

Is there a way to re-arrange the IDE windows for the  *Qt Designer* that is embedded into *Qt Creator* like it is possible with the standalone Designer for *Visual Studio*?

Edit: Note that *Qt Designer* is something like an "app-in-an-app" so it behaves differently to Qt Creators UI.

Comment: I don't how it looks in Visual Studio, but Qt Designer is also a stand-alone tool, check for `designer.exe` in your install path, for example `C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't completely undock views (as in create a completely separate window) in Qt Creator (sadly) but you can rearrange things a little bit:

1. Go to Window -> Views and make sure the *Automatically Hide View Title Bars* is unchecked. This will allow the different views to become movable (and not just resizeable as per default) and partially undock from the IDE. Not that not all views are movable even. For example the sidebar is a completely different animal here and you are stuck with it as it is.
2. Each movable view's title bar contains two buttons (on the right side) - one that enables moving and one that closes the view.
3. Click on the first button and then click on the title bar of the view and drag it around. If you drag it within the IDE Qt Creator will rearrange the other views to free some space (it gives you a nice hint) where you can drop it. If you leave it like that (floating) you can have a pseudo-undocked state of that view.

I use **pseudo-undocked** because (at least on Linux) the view is not actually a separate window and you can't drag it to other workspaces (if you have multiple; not that uncommon in Linux distros). But it's as close as you can get.

Comment: That's it!! Thanks a lot. You saved my Qt-Day ;)